# How to use using-declarations in constraint

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, using-declaration

Is there an alternative to have some `using`-declarations in concept/constraint? Something like:

```
template <typename T>
concept has_begin_v0 = requires (T t)
{
    using std::begin; // KO
    begin(t);
    /*..*/
};
```

The possible ways I have found are:

- use intermediate `namespace`

  ```
  namespace detail
  {
  using std::begin;
  template <typename T>
  concept has_begin_v1 = requires (T t)
  {
      begin(t);
  };
  }
  using detail::has_begin_v1;
  ```

  Introduces extra namespace :-(
- using SFINAEd lambda:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  concept has_begin_v2 = requires (T t)
  {
      [](){
          using std::begin;
          return [](auto&& inner) -> std::void_t<decltype(begin(inner))> {};
      }()(t);
  };
  ```

  Not a fine syntax.
- use "disjunction" of qualified call and adl call:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  concept has_std_begin = requires (T t)
  {
      std::begin(t);
  };

  template <typename T>
  concept has_adl_begin = requires (T t)
  {
      begin(t);
  };

  template <typename T>
  concept has_begin_v3 = has_std_begin<T> || has_adl_begin<T>;
  ```

  The nicer IMO, but seems not to scale nor allow to go further (is `begin(t)` comparable with `end(t)`?).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dqP6EofTv)

Comment: Is it about `begin` specifically? That standard has a solution for some of those functions.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: `begin` is a (nice) example.

Comment: @康桓瑋: indeed, updated gcc version of demo :-)

Comment: Not sure if it is very indicative though. `begin`, `end`, `swap`, all have `std::ranges` overloads that are sfinae friendly and do ADL correctly. Maybe that's an answer too, write niebloids.

Answer (score 3):

You should generally avoid having to do the `using std::begin` trick. Since you're already operating in C++20, you can use the ranges customization point object `std::ranges::begin`. It does the ADL gymnastics you need on a direct call, so you don't need `using std::begin`.